# val() on <option> returns text instead of value in ie7

Tags: jquery

```
$(this).find('select option:selected').each(function (i, val) {

    var selectedValue = $(val).val(); //this returns the text from the option instead of the value
});
```

Is this a known issue in ie7? I didnt find any info about it? Possible workarounds? Thanks

Comment: What version of jQuery are you running?

Comment: This is not the way you should get the selected value. Call `.val()` on the `select` element.

Comment: Fyi, in `.each()` you usually do not need to accept any arguments - the element is also available via `this`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I know, its just an old habit :-) Thanks for telling me though

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'll keep that in mind until next time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs at http://api.jquery.com/val/

`.val()` is only applicable to

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. In the case of `<select
>   multiple="multiple">` elements, the .val() method returns an array
>   containing each selected option; if no option is selected, it returns
>   null.

To achieve what you want, you could just iterate over the `select` and call `.val()` on it, your original code effectively is calling `val()` on `option`, not the actual `select` element, which is why it doesn't really work.

```
$(this).find('select').each(function (i, val) {

    var selectedValue = $(this).val(); 
});
```

`val()` has an added bonus of having the capability to return an array of values in case of `multiple` select: (emphasize mine)

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements
>   such as input, select and textarea. **In the case of `<select
>   multiple="multiple">` elements, the .val() method returns an array
>   containing each selected option**; if no option is selected, it returns
>   null.

Answer (score 0):

try

for single select

```
var selectedValue = $(this).val();
```

you just need to write above line to get selected value nothing else.

for multislect it should  be

```
var result = ""; 
$('#idselect  option:selected').each(function(i, item)
{     
   result += $(this).val() + ", "; 
});
```

Comment: isnt `$(val)` eqvivalent to `$(this)` ?

Comment: I think he means that's all the code you need. He's not replacing just the function code.

Comment: In the OP's code, `this` (at the outermost layer) is clearly **not** a `select` element (it's something that *contains* one or more `select` elements), so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is an expected behavior, since you asking for the value of the option and not the element itself.

Do not overcomplicate things.

```
$(this).find('select').each(function() {
   var val = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: I know that `$(this)` returns a jquery dom element, but what does `this` return?

Comment: @Johan, `this` returns the non jquery wrapped HTML element, that is usually received like `document.getElementById('id')`

Comment: so `this` == `$(this).get(0)` or `$(this)[0]` ?

Comment: @Johan: Yes. E.g., if you're doing the `each` above, `this` will refer to the actual `select` DOM element. `$(this)` calls the jQuery function to put a jQuery wrapper around it so you get all the jQuery goodness. :-)

Comment: @Johan, Exactly... you got it